# Radial Axis plotly express showing floats instead of integers?

Tags: python, plotly

Although my values are integers, the axis is showing floats, how could I correct this using the following?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    r=[1, 5, 2, 2, 3],
    theta=['processing cost', 'mechanical properties', 'chemical stability', 'thermal stability', 'device integration']))

fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True)
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')
fig.show()
```

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the same results sa you. The plot on my end shows integers. Could you add a screenshot and inlcude information about plotly versions etc?

Comment: Same as @vestland. Do you mind to share the output of `plotly.__version__`?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Plotly v4.10.0` which is the most up to date version, and I am encountering a similar problem: when I run your code I get the following polar chart which includes non-integer values in the default range:

[image]

To get around this issue, you can specify the radial tick values manually using the `tickvals` parameter.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    r=[1, 5, 2, 2, 3],
    theta=['processing cost', 'mechanical properties', 'chemical stability', 'thermal stability', 'device integration']))

fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True)
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')

fig.update_layout(
    polar = dict(
        radialaxis = dict(tickvals=[0,1,2,3,4,5], showticklabels=True, ticks=''),
        angularaxis = dict(showticklabels=True, ticks='')
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]